# Error socketio library: "socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by the server"

Tags: python, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a socket that I have configured in NodeJS, from anywhere outside the server if I can connect to the Socket, but when trying to connect from the same server it shows the message: "socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by the server"

The port that I have configured is 8085
I have tried adding:
- http://localhost: 8085
- https://localhost: 8085
- http://127.0.0.1: 8085
- https://127.0.0.1: 8085
- *: 8085
- 192.168.4.7:8085
- PublicIP: 8085

```py
import socketio
sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect('https://localhost:8085')
```

When I connect from outside the server it allows me to interact with the socket. The problem is the local server because it immediately shows me the message "Connection refused"

Comment: Any success on this?

Comment: yep, api nodejs (socketio) did haven't a parameter: 'origins' . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When taking a look at the socketio's [docs](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html), it is shown that there are two or more instances running. One for the **server side** and others for the **client side**.
Let the server file run the server and connect to the server with the client files. An example is given below:

---

##### `server.py`:

```
# using eventlet, visit the docs for more info
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}
})

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)

@sio.event
def my_message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # change the 5000 to any port you want
    # leave the 'localhost' empty string to run on your IP
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('localhost', 5000)), app)
```

##### `client.py`:

```py
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('connection established')

@sio.event
def my_message(data):
    print('message received with ', data)
    sio.emit('my response', {'response': 'my response'})

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')

sio.connect('http://localhost:5000/')
sio.wait()
```

Then, run the `server.py` first:

```
C:\User\new>py server.py
(12080) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Then run `client.py`:

```
C:\User\new>py clinet.py
connection established
```

And your socket file is running.

You will feel easy with this process if you have already experienced with the `socket.io` in JavaScript. Because that is the perfect and most easy way to get started and learn `socket.io`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with origins parameter:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{pingTimeout: 0, pingInterval: 500, origins: '*:*'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same thing. For me it seemed to be an issue in Windows 10: it requires

sio.connect('http://192.168.178.18:8080')

to display the exact IP-address of your computer. Not 'localhost' or anything. Then it connected smoothly.

Comment: Did you use the actual IP address of your computer? Of course that can be different than the example I provided.

Answer (score -1):

Just install requests,
sometimes it doesn't work if we haven't imported requests.
It worked for me
so:
pip install requests